# data base file is not getting created?

Tags: java, mysql, sqlite, jdbc, rdbms

i am trying to create a sqlite data base in a specific folder but when i run the below code, it does not create the data base file?

**code**:

```
/**path to the sqlite database folder that contains all .db files*/
public static final String SQLITE_DATABASE_FOLDER = "c:"+File.separator+"MainWorkspace"+File.separator+"SQLiteDB_Assets"+File.separator+"SQLiteDB";

....
....
....

//in the main method
NodeFactory nodeFactory = new NodeFactory();
    nodeFactory.newSQLiteConn(SysConsts.TEST_DATABASE_NAME);

//member method in NodeFactory class
public void newSQLiteConn(String dbName) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    if (dbName != null) {
        if (!dbName.isEmpty()) {

            this.dbName = dbName;

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            this.dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:"+SysConsts.SQLITE_DATABASE_FOLDER+File.separator+this.dbName;

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "newSQLiteConn", "dbName is empty");
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "newSQLiteConn", "dbName is null");
    }
}
```

please let me know why the data base file is not created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite allows you to set parameters (like page size) before the database file is actually created.

The file is created when you actually write to it (e.g., create a table).

Comment: thanks, and would u please tell me, why settin gthe page size is important

Comment: The page size cannot be changed afterwards.